# Could not get data: Unknown column erro in php and mysql database when calling data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Could not get data: Unknown column erro in php and mysql database when calling data from database
 I need to show the item with subitem as sub category 
I need that item and sub-item both come from database.

like

```
 item1
          -subitem1
          -subitem2
     item2
          -subitem1
     item
```

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM main';
mysql_select_db('vishic3w_packages');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
 die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<ul/><li/> {$row['items']} <br/></li></ul> ";
$items=$row['items'];
{
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subitem where subitem.item = $items ";
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1);
if(! $retval1 )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<ul/><li/> {$row['subitem']} <br/></li></ul> ";
}
}}
```

I want to show the items with their sub items from other table, but after script execute the following error shows

Drinks 
Could not get data: Unknown column 'Drinks' in 'where clause'

the output can be seen herehttp://www.indowesterncaterers.com/catering-packages.php

the databse has these entries shown in the image attached shows the data from table "subitem"

http://s16.postimg.org/6si26jwjp/data.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting single quote around variable "$items" in your query. If it is so, first print the query like below:

```
echo $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subitem where subitem.item = $items ";
```

and try to remove the single quotes.

Comment: yes the error has been removed but null entries, may be due to wrong use of list tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subitem where item like \'$items\'";
```